# NVARCHAR is being cut off in the query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a column in the database which is of the following type: 
Value (nvarchar(150), null)

The data comes from a C#-web application where users paste long pieces of text (they are questions from e-mails). I can only view 150 characters of that piece of text when I query the database, and I can see the whole thing in the web application.

How can I write a query which can get all of it? I've tried casting it as `nvarchar(max)` but that does not work. I've also checked the limit of showing text in Query options which is set at 256. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you possibly using a stored procedure to insert the data? if so check the variable length

Comment: If the field has a limit of 150 characters, it can only contain 150 characters. Changing the field size won't make the lost data reappear. If new data is still truncated at 150 characters, check the code that *inserts* the data. Perhaps you use EF with a field limit of 150 characters, or a stored procedure with an `nvarchar(150)` parameter. Without the code one can only guess

Comment: Probably, there are loads of stored procedures. This web application is bought from an external company so I don't know about all its internals but I'll check them.

Comment: Post the query where you are getting partial value of original.

Comment: @Donald you can't store more than 150 characters in a `nvarchar(150)` field. No casting is going to recover the lost data. Unless you increase the field size you'll always get truncated data. Casting won't recover what was never stored

Answer (score 3):

Casting isn't enough. You need change your column in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ALTER COLUMN Value NVARCHAR (MAX);
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Because your column can store up to 150 characters in this column.

You need to change it to bigger buffer (maybe `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?), then you'll be able to store the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing only 150 character into the column into the table.
Run this

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ALTER COLUMN Value NVARCHAR (MAX);
```

From now it will store maximum of 2Gigabyte into the column.

Be noted that it will not bring back old records, but new records will store in full length.

Comment: Doesn't appear to add anything to the existing answers?